# In headers, should variables be declared as "extern" even if they are class data members?

Tags: c++, c++17

I read in other posts that header variables should be declared using "extern" to prevent multiple definitions / memory allocation if the header is imported into several .cpp files.

Is it also the case when these variables are class data members? I think not because including the class header don't create instances, so I don't see why a memory allocation would occur, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.  To do so generates a [compiler error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PDDQZI48FsPk0UhA).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I read a lot but didn't try doing it.

Comment: You're welcome.  These online compilers (there are several) can be really handy for quickly trying things out.